# Magento 1.7.0.0 - Region Manager Extension Successfully Installed but showing nothing there?

Tags: php, magento

Any reason for seeing this after a successful installation of the 'Region Manager' extension for Magento v1.7.0.0 in the administrative backend?

View image here: ( image hosting publicly for screenshot reference for this post )

[image]

I just ran this code before the installation to fix the 'permissions insufficient" errors and 'settings config file cannot be read/loaded' which fixed the error in Magento Connect.  Do I need to run it again after installing the 'Region Management' extension via SSH?

`find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`

`find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;`

Comment: Did you check your php/magento error logs?

Answer (score 0):

Try flushing your cache from system > configuration > cache management and then try and see if it works. Just for good measure log out and log in after flushing your cache.